# Export jquery plugin and import as module in Angular and use it in directive?

Tags: jquery, angular, plugins

I decided to create a plugin for angular 7. as a sample code:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });

    };

}( jQuery ));

$( "div" ).greenify({
    color: "brown"
});
```

for example in the above code,
1. how to import this in angular as Module?
2. how to use it as directive in angular ( how to use in angular template as directive?)

I am looking for a guidance. thanks in advance.

looking to use like :

`import { MyPlugin } from 'MyPlugin';`

in template:
`<div myplugin></div>` - something like this.

Comment: Don't use jQuery in an Angular app. An Angular directive can have access to the native DOM element and you can make the css changes with TypeScript without having to use jQuery. This all seems like a rather convoluted way of doing thing that you would normally just do with a css class.

Comment: I agree, my matter is different here. I require to use a single library with multiple project with multiple team. I find the jquery plugin much better than explaining all and everything to multiple teams